# TEXTMETRIC is giving wrong height when resizing text with mouse wheel

Tags: winapi, richedit

I'm calculating the number of lines in a rich edit control.

Currently I'm using next code

```
TEXTMETRIC tm; {
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwndRichEdit);
    GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
    ReleaseDC(hwndRichEdit, hdc);
}

RECT editRect;
GetClientRect(hwndRichEdit, &editRect);
long int countLines = (editRect.bottom - editRect.top) / (tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading);
```

The code yields out the right number of lines until I start to change the size of the text via mouse wheel + ctr.

Is it possible to get the right text height even if the text is resized with mouse wheel?

N.B. I'm recalculating the number of lines with `EN_UPDATE` notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an [EM_GETZOOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774208.aspx) message to the control to retrieve the current zoom ratio. Dividing the `countLines` value by the zoom ratio should yield the correct line count. Use the [MulDiv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383718.aspx) API call to implement the division.